# How to add variable as key name in typescript interface?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

This is how my object would look like. This is very small version of object and I have to deal with large object.

```
const obj = {
    name: 'name_key',
    details: 'details_key',
    profile: 'profile_key',
}
```

So, if we want to use value of this object in another object then we can use it like:

```
const newObj = {
    [obj.name]: 'some_value',
    [obj.details]: 'some_value',
    [obj.profile]: 'some_value',
}
```

So, here newObj would become like:

```
newObj = {
    'name_key': 'some_value',
    'details_key': 'some_value',
    'profile_key': 'some_value',
}
```

The same way I want to use it with interface but I'm unable to do so.

```
interface User {
    [obj.name]: string;
    [obj.details]: DetailsInterface;
    [obj.profile]: ProfileInterface;
}
```

I have tried this approach but it throws error like "A computed property name in an interface must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type."
Here DetailsInterface and ProfileInterface are also interface.

I have tried union approach but it doesn't work as all the keys have different types of interface or data type.

Comment: come on, the question isn't related with nestjs. There's no reason to use the `nestjs` tag then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution. The object that we have defined is mutable. So if we use like

```
const obj = {
    name: 'name_key',
    details: 'details_key',
    profile: 'profile_key',
} as const;
```

it becomes unmutable and all the fileds have string value.
Now we can use this object fiels as computing keys name in interface as shown below

```
interface User {
    [obj.name]: string;
    [obj.details]: DetailsInterface;
    [obj.profile]: ProfileInterface;
}
```

So finally interface User becomes like

```
interface User {
    name_key: string;
    details_key: DetailsInterface;
    profile_key: ProfileInterface;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't create a strong-typed interface for something that is defined at runtime, that's not how TypeScript works.

What you could do instead is having a broader interface/type definition that will match with that `obj`, like this:

```
type User = Record<string, any>
```

---

But if `obj` is statically defined, you can generate a interface from it, like so:

[image: code]

I'm unsure if this was what you were looking for tho.